# Can't registerCssFile() from module file using getModule()

Tags: php, yii

Instead of calling/registering the CSS in my view. i want to register it in my `AbcModule.php` since the CSS will be used thru out the module.

```
class Abc extends CWebModule
{

    protected $_assetsUrl;

    public function init()
    {
        $path = Yii::app()->module->getAssetsUrl();

        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($path.'/css/abc.css', 'all');

       $this->setImport(array(
        'abc.models.*',
        'abc.components.*',
       ));

   }

   public function getAssetsUrl()
    {
        if ($this->_assetsUrl === null)
            $this->_assetsUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(__DIR__ . '/assets', false, -1, true);
        return $this->_assetsUrl;
    }
}
```

in the code above i get this error

```
Missing argument 1 for CModule::getModule(), called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/base/CComponent.php on line 111 and defined
```

which is this line

```
$path = Yii::app()->module->getAssetsUrl();
```

i also tried

```
$path = Yii::app()->getModule("Abc")->getAssetsUrl();
```

but got this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAssetsUrl() on a non-object in /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/frontend/modules/research/AbcModule.php on line 17
```

in my view i call it like this. and it works perfect

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($this->module->getAssetsUrl().'/css/abc.css', 'all');
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$path = Yii::app()->module->getAssetsUrl();` or `$path = Yii::app()->controller->module->getAssetsUrl();`

Comment: the 1st one gives me this error `Missing argument 1 for CModule::getModule(), called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/base/CComponent.php on line 111 and defined` the second gives me this `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAssetsUrl() on a non-object in /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/frontend/modules/abc/AbcModule.php on line 14`

Comment: the source of this issue is that getModule function is failing. I am also struggling with this issue, and none of the solution on web is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$path = $this->getAssetsUrl();
```